# Concurrently manage single project across different SCM systems

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

I currently have a project hosted on a private Git repo which I manage using sourcetree. Recently I decided to collaborate with a group of friends on this project. However they prefer Mercurial & SVN to Git and I'd rather have separate Mercurial & SVN repositories created with my project for them to collaborate on while maintaining my own Git repo. I was wondering if it would be possible to do the following via Sourcetree or any other method:

1. Have a single project folder on my work system that tracks my projects onto all three repo's (Git /Mercurial / SVN) concurrently?
2. If 1. is possible, can I then selectively pull changes from either of the versioning systems and also selectively push changes to them ?

I'm using Sourcetree on Mac.
I came across an article by a user who does this for separate repositories on github and bitbucket but I can't recollect the link to share here. 
I'm hoping to find a good way to do this to make managing code easier.
Pardon me if such a question doesn't belong here, the mod's may close this.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How is your question related to `cvs`?  `svn`, `git`, and `cvs` are all a form of VCS.  Are you actually considering using `cvs`, or do you mean to say "VCS"?

Comment: aah sorry, it should've been vcs!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend **do not mix** in single working directory 2 or 3 different VCS. It's just additional headache for maintaining transparent oneness for different engines.

Free working directory for you (all -  Git-centric) is more manageable and less chaotic solution:

- just add single additional remote for each "foreign" repositories - "Mercurial-source" and "SVN-source";
- pull "others" repos, push to "own"

SVN-link can be supported by git-svn, Mercurial-link (from Git side) by ["Mercurial bridge"](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by directly using git repository, hg can access it finely with hg-git extension. But if your intention is to maintain two repository, I think it is feasible too.

Indeed, in a folder, it can have .hg folder for mercurial, .git folder for git, if you mean that. Actually, hg and git distinguish working directory and repository, so this folder can hold different repositories.

For the second question, I think you need to set up some hooks in both hg and git, and let them communicate through hg-git extension of hg, when a push happens in any system. As far as I know, this extension works well.

But for SVN, things go different. Although both hg and git have svn extensions (hgsubversion and git-svn; extension here is a general idea, not specific to hg-like extension) , DVCS systems will branch easily and that causes mapping to svn a bit complex.

Thus, I think hg and git repositories in one folder is feasible through hg-git extension and hooks, and not quite sure about svn.

Comment: Yes I intend to have a copy of my project onto separate mercurial & svn repo's. A post that I came across mentioned cloning each repo with the same base code to a separate folder and then moving the .git folder inside the cloned git folder to the cloned mercurial  folder & then having the git space ignore .hg and vice versa. That didn't work for me though :( It may be some trouble but atleast i'd like to have hg & git working for me preferably via some IDE. Any thoughts or tutorials you could point me to?

Comment: Signle Working Dir with two (Git&Hg) repos is more headache, than fun. Adding SVN convert it into **real nightmare**. Do not give harmful advice

Comment: How does this work then? http://geekswithblogs.net/gregorymalcolm/archive/2012/03/17/mirroring-mercurial-and-git-changes-the-lazy-way.aspx Its the article i was referring to in my question.

Comment: @Kevin - it works, yes, and I doesn't tell you "it will not work", but - you want toi fight with trobles or write code? Greg described rather easy and plain situation (and even in it he made mistake in ignores), more complex use-case (can) give more troubles

Comment: @Kevin In hg-git, when pull from a git repo, hg-git will keep a .git folder automatically in the same folder. A.k.a, there will be `repo/.git` and `repo/.hg` at the same time, after you do `hg pull ../some-git-repo`. So this folder is both hg and git repo, and you will have a separate git repo, too.

Comment: @sherlock - "hg-git will keep a .git folder automatically in the same folder" is wrong statement. Git repo stored in `.hg/git/`

Comment: @LazyBadger Thank you for pointing out. I am using hg-git 2320ab6ada364053848ae69cb07a61b1fce1aaba on windows, .git folder is in the same level with .hg. I will check that later, to see if it results from my settings. Thank you!

Comment: @LazyBadger wow, ok I will check my settings, really thank you for pointing out that.